# git clone fails without any obvious reason

Tags: git, clone, debian-buster

git clone doesn't fail but it doesn't clone anything either :

```
Linux mybox 3.8.13.30 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 26 17:53:58 CEST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=true
export GIT_TRACE=true

git clone https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git
15:43:35.988459 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git clone 
https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git
Cloning into 'tg'...
15:43:48.563749 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin 
https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git

git --version
15:48:55.165056 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git version
git version 2.20.1
```

Nothing is downloaded, not even the target folder is created where the code is suppose to be checked out.

I do have write permission to the current folder, and I can clone the same repo on a different machine on the same network the network-wise I'm OK.

What can it be? What else can I check?

`ls` to the directory:

```
user@mybox:~/tmp/tmp$ ls -la 
total 8 
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun 9 16:47 . 
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 Jun 9 16:45 .. 
user@mybox:~/tmp/tmp$ git clone github.com/vysheng/tg.git 
16:47:59.808142 git.c:418 trace: built-in: git clone 
github.com/vysheng/tg.git 
Cloning into 'tg'... 
16:48:00.516893 run-command.c:643 trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin github.com/vysheng/tg.git 
user@mybox:~/tmp/tmp$ ls -la 
total 8 
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun 9 16:48 . 
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 Jun 9 16:45 ..
```

Comment: What makes you think it didn't clone? Can you show an `ls` in the directory in which you've executed the `git clone ` command?

Comment: the folder where you are cloning is empty?

Comment: <pre>
user@mybox:~/tmp/tmp$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun  9 16:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 Jun  9 16:45 ..
user@mybox:~/tmp/tmp$ git clone https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git
16:47:59.808142 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git clone https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git
Cloning into 'tg'...
16:48:00.516893 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git
user@mybox:~/tmp/tmp$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun  9 16:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 Jun  9 16:45 ..
</pre>

Comment: I'm not sure how to format properly the comment above... it's just a listing of the content of the folder before and after the cloning...

Comment: please, edit your question and add the formatted trace of the comment above

Comment: just did.
Additionally I've checked the git executable with ldd and all the shared libraries look alright

Comment: I got a bit further....
I've tried to **strace** git. The output is obviously huge but I can see creating the target folder but then some for obscure reason decides to remove it.

Comment: try to give a different name to the destination folder:

`git clone github.com/vysheng/tg.git tg_dest_folder`

Comment: according to the tracelog git tries to run
`/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https origin https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git`.
If I try to run this manually I get a **Segmentation fault**... so that's what I'm checking right now

Comment: Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

#0  0xb6ab4784 in nettle_yarrow256_update () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.6

Comment: bingo : [https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=910907]

Comment: actually this is more to the point (at least the hardware corresponds) : [ https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=242065 ]